# Do we need "The" in front of "Istanbul Chamber of Commerce"

Tags: prepositions

On the Chamber of Commerce building in Istanbul I saw that they wrote their name as "The İstanbul Chamber of Commerce". I thought that it is wrong to put "the" before İstanbul.

The correct way, I think, should be "İstanbul Chamber of Commerce" or "The Chamber of Commerce of İstanbul". Am I right? If so can you explain why?

Thanks.

Comment: Even though English isn't the native language in Istanbul, it's *entirely up to the organisation* what they call themselves. Grammar and pedantry are largely irrelevant to such contexts. Regarding *it is wrong to put "the" before İstanbul,* how do you square that with, for example, [***The** British Museum*?](http://www.britishmuseum.org/)

Comment: Yes I saw also The British Chamber of Commerce in Turkey. But I feel British is different than a city name. For instance, it is New York Chamber of Commerce and not The New York Chamber of Commerce. British, it seems, refers to "inhabitants of Great Britain" and not a place name.

Comment: @zeynel:  http://www.chamber.nyc/about.html has a heading "**Greater New York Chamber of Commerce**" and starts its first paragraph "*The Greater New York Chamber of Commerce is a ...*".  Neither is wrong

Comment: Google Books says it has 88 instances of [London Underground was closed](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22london+underground+was+closed%22), which should include all those *without* a definite article as well as those that do include it. And given it says it has 50 instances of [**the** London Underground was closed,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+london+underground+was+closed%22)  I think we could reasonably say it's six of one and half-a-dozen of the other. This isn't a matter of grammar though - it's just naming conventions.

Comment: I understand what is bothering me. Do we say "The New York"? No. New York is a specific place and there is no reason to make it more specific by prefixing with a "the". For instance, if I say "I'm going to New York tomorrow" you may ask, if my statetement doesn't seem plausible to you, "*the* New York?"   But in usual situations there is no reason to say "The New York" "The" in "The İstanbul CofC" appears superfluous and refers to Chamber of Commerce and not to İstanbul. Because İstanbul is a unique place and there is no reason to make it more specific by adding a "the". Does this make sense?

Comment: This page says do not use definite article the before "names of cities, towns, or states: Seoul, Manitoba, Miami"
https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/

Comment: And yet it’s “ The Ohio State University”.  When it comes to instituions it appears to be a matter of taste, even if the beginning of the institution’s name is a city, state, or country.   SOURCE: The New York Public Library.

Comment: So it looks like it is a matter of taste. Then let me ask the question this way: Is there a difference in meaning between "The Ohio State University" and "Ohio State University"? For instance "Texas University" chose to name itself without using "the". Is there a loss in meaning? How does it sound to native speakers with or without "the"?

Comment: The article isn't for **Istanbul**. It's for **chamber**, which is pre-modified by **Istanbul**. Don't look at the noun which comes immediately after the determiner. Look instead at the head noun of the noun phrase.

Comment: I worked at four different ones in my professional life. As a building plaque, you can use the or not.

Comment: In a formal sign, The X of Y is fine.

Comment: But @Lambie, the issue here isn't _The X of Y_, it's _The Y X_.

Comment: @ColinFine **The** Istanbul Chamber **of** Commerce. The Office of the Prime Minister//The Office of the President. The issue is x of y. The sign on the building is fine.

Comment: @Lambie: ah, I see what you mean. I took "Chamber of Commerce" to be an atomic term for the purposes of the discussion. Are you really suggesting that Istanbul modifies "Chamber", not "Chamber of Commerce"?

Comment: @ColinFIne I really do not understand why you ask me that. Of course, Istanbul modifies: chamber of commerce: Istanbul Chamber of Commerce.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you should use the article. The definite article 'the' is used when something is unique. There are many chambers of commerce, but your example is one specific chamber of commerce. Which chamber? *The Istanbul Chamber of Commerce*.

There may be exceptions. Another answer contains a photo of the organisation's logo which features the abbreviation ICC and no article - this isn't surprising. Consider *The United Nations*, commonly abbreviated to 'UN', and usually referred to in this form as "*the UN*". However, "UN" is often used as a label for other things that belong to the United Nations, for example, "UN Peacekeepers". For things like that, the article is omitted. Likewise with your example, you might refer to the Istanbull Chamber of Commerce as "*the ICC*" but to something that belonged to them, such as their offices, as "ICC headquarters".

Answer (score 0):

Although cities, states, counties, and countries do not normally require "the" in American English, institutions like libraries, universities, and museums will often include the name of their city or state in their names.  So we have "The New York Public Library" and "The Ohio State University" as examples, in addition to The New York Times.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, chambers of commerce are preceded by one or two nouns that act as an adjective. Logos and signs do not usually have "the":

International Chamber of Commerce [Paris]

[image: International]

British-American Chamber of Commerce [on a logo or sign]

[image: Franco British]

French-American Chamber of Commerce.

Now, on a sign, usually, no article is used.

Very often, the official signs do not include the "the", except in writing where they are part of a sentence.

**The** French-American Chamber of Commerce promotes business between France and the United States.

I have posted just two pictures. That is enough.

So: Istanbul Chamber of Commerce [on a sign]

If they want the, so be it. But it is not usual.